# Possessive Pronouns- Are 'el'/'la' interchangeable with 'mi'?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, artículos, posesivos

To elaborate, take the sentence

> Hago **la** cama.

This means ‘I make my bed’.

However, the sentence

> Hago **mi** cama.

Means the same. My question is are these interchangeable for all instances where the sentence goes [verb] [pronoun] [noun]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex, yet interesting problem. Mainly, because among non-native speakers it's quite confusing.

To put it simple: Definite articles **can be interchangeable** with the possessive adjective, **but it hugely depends on the context**.

As discussed by [Said-Mohand (2010)](https://marcoele.com/descargas/10/said-articulo_definido.pdf) and [King & Suñer (1999)](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Gram%C3%A1tica_espa%C3%B1ola.html?id=2J4vDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y), in Spanish it's common to use the definite article as a possessive **when the "owner" of the object can easily be inferred (contextually or using the reflexive)**. This is why we use the article instead of the possessive when talking about parts of the body. Look at these examples:

`Me duele la cabeza` translates as: `My head hurts`.

`¿Sabes qué tengo en la mano?` translates as `Do you know what I have in my hand?`

However, as discussed in the aforementioned references, we must use the possessive when 1) we want to talk about autonomous objects and ignore whatever relation it holds with the speaker, and 2) we don't have extra information on who is the owner of the object. Look at these examples:

`El doctor hizo unas cuantas puntadas en su mano` translates as: `The doctor gave him some stitches in his hand`. In this context, the relationship between the `hand` and the owner (`he`) is not important, so we don't use the definite article.

`Tu coche está allí` translates as: `Your car is there`. We can't use `El coche está allí` and still translate as `Your car is there` because `El coche está allí` is ambiguous and we don't have any information about the relationship between the object and any of the persons taking part in this dialogue.

Going back at your example:

`Hago la cama` is not `Hago my cama`. We would need extra info to properly assume that `la` is used as a possessive.

Comment: Be careful with all of this translations, because **hago la cama** means **I make the bed** but if in the context, let's say that his mom asked him **what are you doing** and he's at **his room** you can understand that the mentioned **bed** it's his also, so as in Spanish you avoid pronouns repetition also when those are understood by context you will answer **hago la cama**, but if he sleep with his brother at the same room and he's only making his bed, he would say **hago mi cama** to specifically say which one he is making. So it's all question of redundancy and context.

Comment: So this apply to the examples: **_Me_ duele la cabeza**, **¿Sabes que tengo en la mano?** and **El coche está allí**. And again the context matter at the example **El doctor hizo unas cuantas puntadas en _su_ mano** while this can be understood as **his own hand**, the doctor's hand, or some other male's hand.

Answer (score 6):

The sentence:

> Hago **la** cama.

is ambiguous, as it may mean "I make my bed" (in which case it is equivalent to: *Hago **mi** cama*) or may be used to mean that the person makes some other bed specified in the context.

However, unlike in English, it is usual in Spanish to use the definite article instead of the possessive to mean somebody makes their own bed.

Alternatively, a pronoun can be used to make clear you make your own bed:

> **Me** hago **la** cama.

One can even hear the redundant:

> **(Yo) Me** hago **mi** cama.

to mean that the speaker only makes his/her own bed, or makes his/her bed by him/herself. In this case it is usual to make the subject explicit.

Note: I'd like to clarify something after reading the other answer, mostly focused on parts of the body. When parts of the body are not involved, the use of the definite article is mainly due to the fact that the person only has one bed, or even one car: *Tengo el auto afuera* (meaning: My car's outside.) The singular feature does not apply to parts of the body.